# What is the best way for Files IO in java

Tags: java, file, io, large-files, filechannel

I need to do some basic operations on image file in java . My requirements are like :
- opening a file.
- read bytes in some order. 
- write the updated byte at the particular offset
- seeking at some offset in file.

Files can be of any size like 2 GB image files.

I want to know, which class in java can provide me the flexibility to do all these operations with ease and with performance efficiency, considering IO in java is slow.

Currently I am considering FileChannel, but I dont know about its performance with files of larger size like in GB. Also it use to read file bytes in ByteBuffer, but if file is large enough , is it appropriate to read all the bytes at same time or should read in chunks. If I read data in chunks, what is the proper size of a chunk?

Please guide me.

Thanks

Comment: ‘Considering I/O in Java is slow’: where did you get that motion. I/O is I/O. It’s affected by several things, but the language is among the least of them.

Answer (score 2):

You probably should use [RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html), it supports seek by position and write. Also I don't think it is accurate to describe IO in Java as slow, often you can achieve C like performance if you use java.io properly.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Java 8 Stream features

```
Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(args[1]));
```

But, If you are not using Java-8. You use `java.nio` package

> If I read data in chunks, what is the proper size of a chunk?

You can uses a buffer size of only 1 KB.

Comment: Images don't have lines, and the problem statement requires random access.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
//readfile(byte stream)
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream("d:\\1.txt");
    //output file
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("d:\\2.txt");
    //read data
    //how many bytes read in once
    byte[] bytes = new byte[2048];
    //receive data (n represents relative data,in this case, it's numeric )
    int n = -1;
    //loop get data
    while ((n = in.read(bytes,0,bytes.length)) != -1) {
        //transform to string
        String str = new String(bytes,0,n,"GBK"); # byte->string
        System.out.println(str);
        //write data
        out.write(bytes, 0, n);
    }
    //close stream
    in.close();
    out.close();
```

Comment: Doesn’t answer the question.